# discrete mathematics question $2-2\times 7+2\times 7^2− \cdots +2(-7)^n = \frac{1-(-7)^{n+1}}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

This question is from the book Discrete Mathematics and its Applications by Kenneth Rosen page 329. Again for question 8 I face the same probelm I know the solution but I do not understand it.

Question 8) Prove that:  $2 − 2\times 7 + 2\times 7^2 − \cdots + 2(−7)^n = \frac{1−(−7)^{n+1}}{4}$ whenever $n$ is a nonnegative integer.

[image]

The answer:
[image]
[image]

The problem is I don't understand it especially the last part I marked in red can someone explain it to me please?

Comment: This is proven through induction.

Comment: I know but the problem is I don't understand it how did we got from (1−(−7)^k+1 + 8×(−7)^k+1)/4 to (1+7×(−7)^k+1)/4

Comment: It's just  $\frac{1+(8-1)(-7)^{k+1}}{4}$ nothing more

Comment: ok but where did we get the minus 1 from?

Comment: In the numerator, we have $1 - a + 8 a = 1 + 7 a$ (combine like terms) where $a = (-7)^{k+1}.$

Comment: oh yeah ok  thank you so much now it slowly starts to make sense but then how did book take (1+7×(−7)k+1)/4 and get (1−(−7)×(−7)^k+1)/4

Comment: Having two negative signs in front of a number is the same as having no negatives at all. Thus, $7 = -(-7).$ Now, why did they choose to replace something nice like $7$ with something that looks a little uglier? Well, we want a $-7$ somewhere because the problem deals with powers of $-7.$

Comment: As a tip, you should @ someone if you want them to get a notification on your reply. I just happened to revisit and noticed that you responded. You will always get a notification because you made the original post; others won’t unless you @ their username. Also, please visit the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It’s hard to read the math you type since it’s not properly typeset.

Comment: @shoteyes Thank you so much Sir god bless you. You've made my dilema go away I promise last question: from (1−(−7)×(−7)^k+1)/4 how did we get (1×(−7)^(k+1)+1)/4

Comment: $(-7)*(-7)^{k+1}=(-7)^{(k+1)+1}$. The same thing as $2*2^2=2^3$

Comment: @zpearce I think I understand what you are saying it makes I think I now have a clear  picture of how the book reached the final solution. Thank you all very much god bless you all I heard it is possible to award points and mark my question as solved how do I do this?

Comment: Click the checkmark under a posted answer :). You are not able to accept comments as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

\begin{align}
[2-2*7+2*7^2-...+2*(-7)^{k}]+2*(-7)^{k+1} &=\frac{1-(-7)^{k+1}+8(-7)^{k+1}}{4}\\
&=\frac{1+8(-7)^{k+1}-1(-7)^{k+1}}{4}
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm sorry but your method looks a little bit difficult to understand shoteyes in the comment section made it easier he said just imagine as: a=(−7)^k+1

Comment: $-1a+8a=8a-1a=7a$